# Conditional statement for WordPress Shortcodes

Tags: php, wordpress, conditional-statements

I have two shortcodes setup: 
`[easy_options id="companyName"]`
and
`[easy_options id="companyLogo"]`

I'm wanting WordPress to check if `[easy_options id="companyLogo"]` holds data (an image upload), if not display `[easy_options id="companyName"]` (plain text)...

Is this possible? If so could anyone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put condition to check ID like below.

```
function your_short_code_function($atts) {
    $options = shortcode_atts(array(
       'id' => ''
    ), $atts, "easy_options");

   if($options['id'] == "companyLogo") {
       //an image upload
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using switch case as follow:

```
function easy_options_shortcodes( $atts ) {
extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    'id' => 'companyName' //cosidering a defaultvalue

), $atts ) );

switch( $id ){
    case 'companyName': 
        $output = '<div class="classcompanyName"></div>';
        break;

    case 'companyLogo': 
        $output = '<div class="companyLogo"></div>';
        break;

    default:
        $output = '<div class="defaultshortcodecontent"></div>';
        break;
  }

   return $output;
}

add_shortcode( 'easy_options', 'easy_options_shortcodes' );
```